# The action index is not defined in controller

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I'm learning from tutorial and trying to view my ItemesController but i'm always getting the following error:
" Missing Method in ItemsController. The action index is not defined in controller ItemsController"

I typed this url: localhost/cake_2_5/Items

the path of ItemesController.php:

/var/www/html/cake_2_5/app/Controller

```php
<?php
class ItemsController extends AppController
{
    public function idex(){

        $this->set('color', 'blue');

    }
}
?>
```

The path of my index.ctp:
/var/www/html/cake_2_5/app/View/Items

```php
<?php echo $color ?>
```

Release Notes for CakePHP 2.5.0.

Comment: `public function idex()` typo?

Comment: i thinks so, by default the route is set to index function not to idex,so check your spelling and try it again